# Why is the int.TryParse returning false everytime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The `testCards` string picks up the value from web.config. But every time I try to use `int.tryParse` it gives a `false` value when I try to parse the string `testCards`. Any idea what I might be missing?

```xml
<add key ="TestCards" value ="4987654321098769,4111111111111111,4987654321098769"/>
```

```cs
string testCards = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestCards"];
int flag=0
bool isSuceeded=false
isSuceeded = int.TryParse(testCards, out flag);
```

Comment: Why oop is tagged here?

Comment: That value is not a valid int. Just read it as a string.

Comment: If you're trying to parse that as a single 32-bit integer, it's not going to fit. If you're trying to parse that as three 32-bit integers, you need to split it and parse each one.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Each one is way bigger than 32 bits anyway.

Comment: @HereticMonkey even if the string is split into three parts, each of of them is way out of range of an int32

Comment: Use `string.Split` and to validate the credit card number something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32965555/284240

Comment: @GSerg Didn't say parsing each one would *work* :)

Comment: Creditcard numbers are *strings*, even if they consist of only digits. (proof: "add 1" or "multiply by 2" are meaningless operations)

Comment: This question is missing a statement that defines what the _expected_ result was.  It's unclear what you intended to have happen if it returned `true`, specifically: what you expected the value of `flag` to be.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an `int`! It has commas in it, and if it didn't have commas the number is much bigger than an `int` can hold in any .NET platform.

I'm gathering from the name `TestCards` that these are intended to be credit card numbers? In that case they should be strings.